# How to create a view on top of one view?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am creating a simple android application. for my login page I want to have a background picture and another view at top of it like the sample that I have below (imagine the black part is my background picture and the green part is the view with a description and two button!) Right now I set the background picture to my relative layout activity and I am using the alert dialog for the view that I was talking about!

I was wondering is there any better and cleaner way to do this? because with the alert diaolog there are lots of cases that I need to take care of!

Thank you very much
[image]

Comment: add one more Relativelayout inside your relative layout and set layout_alignParentBottom="true", and inside this new relative layout add the description textview and buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/description"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Button2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your feedback! your code is working however in my real code instead of the description I want to add an image <imageView> but when I done that then nothing came up! Any Idea why?

Comment: You want to set background image for bottom view or just one image view above the button.?

Comment: instead of this:
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
I added this
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Fuzi"
            android:src="@drawable/fuzz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your relative layout in a linear layout (with vertical orientation attribute) for your activity and then add into it the image and the login pannel.
In this way you can arrange the views like as rows!
Below a silmple xml example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >


              inser the image view .. 

              insert the login pannel


</LinearLayout>
```